# How To add-trusted-cert on a Mac Remotely (without user interaction)

Tags: macos, security

Is it possible to add a trusted certificate on a Mac OS X 10.8.3 remotely? If so, how?

My current approach is to use the command below. Can it be tweaked so that it works remotely without user interaction?

```
security add-trusted-cert foo.cer
```

When I try the command above, I get `SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings: The authorization was denied since no user interaction was possible.`

My situation: the tool I'm using executes `/bin/sh -xe bar.sh` on the target machine and I have control over [1] which user it executes as and [2] the contents of `bar.sh` which currently has `security add-trusted-cert foo.cer`. Unlocking the keychain first does not appear to be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The command below works but the password can be seen by another user with `ps` and maybe even ends up in a commmand-line history as well. *If there's a better answer that avoids this problem, most likely I'll mark that one as the accepted answer.*

`echo "password" | sudo -S /usr/bin/security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /path/to/keychain /path/to/cert`

I got it from [http://www.bynkii.com/archives/2009/04/stupid_cert_tricks.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20120324035705/http://www.bynkii.com/archives/2009/04/stupid_cert_tricks.html)

Comment: If you prefix your command with a space, it will be omitted from command history.